# Two Threads Listening to one input stream

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have a client server android application that mirrors the screen of the server,
the server sends screenshots overtime using dataoutputstream, and the client receives it and set it as a source for the image view. What i want to achieve is that when i click a button, i will write a string to the client and execute a task but i'm having problems doing. I create two threads that reads to the same input stream.

How can i listen to a string that will arrive while accepting the image sending by the server.

Thread 1 run method for listening to arriving images

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        //update UI for the stream
        Log.d("ShareService", "client side started");
        try {
            while (isConnected) {
                final byte[] bytes;
                int len = mDataInputStream.readInt();
                bytes = new byte[len];
                if (len > 0) {
                    mDataInputStream.readFully(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                }
                clientActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ImageView iv = clientActivity.findViewById(R.id.image_view_screen_share);
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                });
                bitmapReceive++;
                Log.d("Share Service", "Bitmap received: " + bitmapReceive);
            }
            Log.d("Share Service", "Client Disconnects");
            disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thread 2 run method for listening to arriving commands

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("ShareService", "screen pinning listener started");
            while (isConnected) {
                try {
                    String command = mDataInputStream.readUTF();
                    Log.d("ShareService", "Command has been received: " + command);
                    switch (command) {
                        case SCREEN_PIN_ON:
                            //start screen pinning
                            Log.d("ShareService", "ScreenPinning is on");
                            clientActivity.startLockTask();
                            break;
                        case SCREEN_PIN_OFF:
                            //stop screen pinning
                            Log.d("ShareService", "ScreenPinning is off");
                            clientActivity.stopLockTask();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this error message on thread 2

```
W/System.err: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 0
W/System.err:     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
W/System.err:     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
W/System.err:     at com.example.android.presentor.screenshare.ShareService$Client$1.run(ShareService.java:267)
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: i've included the error i get.

Comment: And? .. Please comment on the error yourself first.

Comment: `a button, i will write a string to the client and execute a task` ??? A button where? On your server? Why would you want to write a string? Who writes the string? The server or the client? What kind of task? Edit your post to answer please?

Comment: `I create two threads that reads to the same input stream.`. Why would you? What for? And does it cause the error? Elaborate in your post also.

Comment: You cannot let two threads read from the same inputstream of course. Well.. Not at the same time.

Comment: From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html): "DataInputStream is not necessarily safe for multithreaded access. Thread safety is optional and is the responsibility of users of methods in this class."

Comment: This Is Never Going To Work. Rethink.